# put brackets around negative numbers flextable

Tags: r, flextable

I have a flextable composed on both positive and negative numbers.

I would like to format the negative numbers to have brackets around them, as opposed to a `-` sign.

```
ft <- flextable( data.frame(col1 = -1:1) )
ft
```

[image]

I would like to see:

[image]

as shown from `library(formattable)`'s `accounting(c(-1:1))`

I tried:

```
ft <- flextable( data.frame(col1 = -1:1) )
ft <- set_formatter( x = ft,
                     col1 = function(x) bracket_neg_num( x)
)
ft
```

to no avail, where bracket_neg_num:

```
bracket_neg_num = function(x){
  if ( x < 0){
    paste0("(",abs(x),")")
  } else if (x == 0){
    "-"
  } else{
    x
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vectorizing you should use `ifelse` like this:

```r
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable( data.frame(col1 = -1:1) )
ft <- set_formatter( x = ft,
                     col1 = function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste0("(",abs(x),")"), x))
ft
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Quinten solution is totally valid, but I'd like to show another solution with `mk_par/compose`:

```r
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(data.frame(col1 = -1:1))
ft <- mk_par(ft, i = ~ col1 < 0, value = as_paragraph(as_bracket(abs(col1))))
ft
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the accepted solution is in the R spirit whereas David's solution is more in the flextable philosophy.