# combining flextable formatting of negative numbers with NA and big mark

Tags: r, flextable

following on from

I have

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c(NA,10000,-1,0), col2 = 1:4)
```

I would like:

- have negative numbers surrounded by brackets as mentioned in [put brackets around negative numbers flextable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883172/put-brackets-around-negative-numbers-flextable/73883646#73883646)
- have blank values shown as `N/A`
- show big marks as a `,`

I can do it separately with:

```
flextable(data.frame(col1 = c(NA,10000,-1,0), col2 = 1:4)) %>%
  colformat_num(
    big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = ".",
    na_str = "N/A")
```

and

```
flextable(data.frame(col1 = c(NA,10000,-1,0), col2 = 1:4)) %>%
  set_formatter(col1 = function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste0("(",abs(x),")"), ifelse(x == 0, paste("-"), ifelse(is.na(x), paste("N/A"),x))))
```

but when combining them, does not reveal the way I would like:

```
flextable(data.frame(col1 = c(NA,10000,-1,0), col2 = 1:4)) %>%
  colformat_num(
    big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = ".",
    na_str = "N/A") %>%
  set_formatter(col1 = function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste0("(",abs(x),")"), ifelse(x == 0, paste("-"), ifelse(is.na(x), paste("N/A"),x))))
```

I would like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `format` with `big.mark` and use `set_flextable_default` like this:

```r
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(col1 = c(NA,10000,-1,0), col2 = 1:4)
set_flextable_defaults(na_str = "NA", big.mark = ",")
flextable(data.frame(col1 = c(NA,10000,-1,0), col2 = 1:4)) %>%
  set_formatter(col1 = function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste0("(",abs(x),")"), 
                                   ifelse(x == 0, paste("-"), 
                                   ifelse(is.na(x), "NA",
                                   ifelse(x > 100, format(x, big.mark = ','), x)))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Some code for your comment:

```r
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(col1 = c(NA,10000,-1,0), col2 = 1:4)
set_flextable_defaults(na_str = "NA", big.mark = ",")
flextable(data.frame(col1 = c(NA,10000,-1234,0), col2 = 1:4)) %>%
  set_formatter(col1 = function(x) ifelse(x < 0, paste0("(",format(abs(x), big.mark = ','),")"), 
                                   ifelse(x == 0, paste("-"), 
                                   ifelse(is.na(x), "NA",
                                   ifelse(x > 100, format(x, big.mark = ','), x)))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thats great @Quinten, that works, but testing  `-1234` does not appear as `(1,234)`, just `(1234)`. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Hi @frank, I added some code for that. You could use a `format` to `abs`.